# How to enable one instance of form in angular4 from multiple forms

Tags: angular, forms, angular4-forms, dynamicform

I have created multiple dynamic forms according to data coming from backend JSON and using edit, save, cancel function buttons there. But When I Edit one form, which has the logic to enable the disabled form using flags, all the forms get enabled. I just want one form to be enabled. Here is my Code for the form :

```
<form class="application-form" class="form-group"#appform="ngForm">
                                                <div class="form-section-detail row">
                                                        <ng-container *ngFor="let fieldItem of sectionItem.sectionFieldList">
                                                                <div class="col-md-4" *ngIf="checkForFieldsVisibility(fieldItem,pageInfoBeans,sectionItem)">
                                                                        <app-form  [fieldInfo]="fieldItem" [pageInfoBeans]="pageInfoBeans" [formEnableInd]="enableEditIndicator"></app-form>
                                                                </div>

                                                        </ng-container>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="btn-row row">

                                                        <button  *ngIf="!showSaveCancelButtons"  type="button" class="btn modal-btn btn-default" (click)="isEditClicked()"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                                                        <button  *ngIf="showSaveCancelButtons" class="btn modal-btn btn-default" (click)="saveCreditApplication();showEditButtonOnSave() "><i class="fa fa-check fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                        <button  *ngIf="showSaveCancelButtons" type="button" (click)="showEditButton()" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn modal-btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-times fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>

                                                </div>
                                        </form>
```

And the form switch contions are(App Form) :

```
<ng-template #showInput>
        <div class="col-md-8 " [ngSwitch]="fieldInfo.dataTypeName">
                <input *ngSwitchCase="'Text'" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="pageInfoBeans.nameValueMap[fieldInfo.name]" name="{{fieldInfo.name}}"
                        [required]="fieldInfo.requiredInd" [maxLength]="fieldInfo.fieldSize==0?5:fieldInfo.fieldSize" [disabled]="formEnableInd">

                <input *ngSwitchCase="'Email Address'" type="email" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="pageInfoBeans.nameValueMap[fieldInfo.name]" name="{{fieldInfo.name}}"
                        [required]="fieldInfo.requiredInd" [maxLength]="fieldInfo.fieldSize==0?5:fieldInfo.fieldSize" [disabled]="formEnableInd"></ng-template>
```

So there is n number of forms created with this code initially disabled than on Edit I just need one to be enabled for which I click Edit.
Please suggest.